# REST - how to model relations with relation data

Tags: rest, relationship, restful-architecture

Say I have the following two root resources:

```
.../organizations
.../persons
```

A `GET` on `.../organizations/id` returns all the information about a specific organization, such as the name, location, etc.

A `GET` on `.../persons/id` returns all the information about a specific person, such as the name, age, gender, etc.

What is the preferred RESTful way to model the membership of a person in an organization (for retrieval and creation)? I do not only want to model the membership itself, but also add extra properties, such as the date on which the person joined the organization, his/her role in the organization, ...

Some thoughts:

- If we provide `.../organizations/id/persons/id`, what should a `GET` return? Only the membership data (join data, role, ...) and a link to `.../persons/id`? The REST API user can use the link to fetch all the information about the person.
- Do we provide a possibility to `POST` to `.../persons` for creating a person, and another/separate `POST` to `.../organizations/id/persons` for creating the membership?
- Going further, let's say a person must always be member of at least one organization. In that case, we need one `POST` for atomically creating the person and the membership at the same time.

  How do we model that? Preferably, I would like to keep the root resources `.../organizations` and `.../projects`. It doesn't make sense to create a person on `.../organizations/id/persons`, neither it does make sense to create a membership on `.../persons/`.

Comment: Quite a bit of duplicity here I think ...
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429924/rest-relation-context
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427115/rest-relations-and-etag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't using [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and its simple format fulfil your needs?

Let's suppose we have defined resources for persons, organizations and memberships
and we are attempting to retrieve information related to a person identified by "42".

Request:

```
GET /persons/42 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/hal+json
```

Response:

```
HTTP1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Smith",
    "firstName": "John",

    "organization": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "blah",
        "href": "http://myserver/organizations/1234"
    },

    "membership": {
        "id": 5678,
        "name": "blih",
        "href": "http://myserver/memberships/5678"
    },

    "_links": {
        "self" : {
            "href" : "http://myserver/persons/42"
        }
    }
}
```

The person resource refers to the parent organization through the "organization" 
relation. That relation allows you to easily navigate to the corresponding organization 
resource through the corresponding href link.

In the same manner, the membership relations allows to access the corresponding
membership data (once again through the "href" link), if you consider that membership
associates one person to one organization.

Request:

```
GET /memberships/5678 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/hal+json
```

Response:

```
HTTP1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/hal+json
{
    "id": 5678,
    "name": "blih",

    "person": {
        "id": 42,
        "href": "http://myserver/persons/42"
    },

    "organization": {
        "id": 1234,
        "href": "http://myserver/organizations/1234"
    },

    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://myserver/memberships/5678"
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm not saying that the modelisation above is the right one for your 
needs (one person can probably belong to several organizations, for example, and you then need an array in the serialization).

My point is that using HAL might help you modelize what you want.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll take a look into more detail later on. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting! I am still not sure whether I want a separate `membership` resource or not. I added another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429924/rest-relation-context.

Comment: doesn't really reply the question but it is a good source of information, well written. HAL is more useful for read-only API's, so if you're going to do a lot of state transfer take a look at Siren or Collection-JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a resource an object that could exist independently without a dependency to another object. This is just a guideline and you can see how it works in terms of your `projects` and `organizations`.

The way I see it a `membership` should be it's independent resource, because it could even exist after the resource `person` has been deleted, for historical purposes for example.

In that model I would create a resource `/memberships`, because it's not a property of a `person` or an `organization` that would prompt you to add that as a `person` or `organization` sub-resource.

I'm not sure if I agree with @hellraiser, perfect would be hard to define even by Roy's standards. I usually try to achieve the higher level of REST as described by Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: A separate membership resource does make sense. But what about the requirement that a person must be member of at least one organization. Where do we `POST` that? We are creating two independent resources at the same time (the person and the membership). Preferably, we do this atomically, to avoid orphans.

Comment: if the membership cannot exists without the person it's linked to it as a sub-resource.

Comment: and it does make sense to POST a person which internally creates both person and membership. That would be your point number 2.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, perfect RESTful API design is unreachable. I've never seen a system that satisfies all REST API theses formulated by Roy Fielding. But you can improve your skills of rest api design from project to project by following best practises.
For the first time, look this [article](http://codeplanet.io/principles-good-restful-api-design/).

Comment: Good advice, but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Thanks for link, I certainly will take a look. Although it does not answer my question, the feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If talking closer to the subject:

Comment: I'd recommend to design api for data manipulation of 3 entites: Organization, Person, Employee(relations between Organization and Person, i suppose 1 Person could have >1 role in organization). So you need ../organizations/*, ../persons/*, ../employee/* services. I prefer to avoid paths like ../organization/id/persons/id, because if you have more entites and relations between them, it could be difficult to maintain such architecture.