# rest - relations and etag

Tags: rest, etag

Say I have two root resources:

```
/organizations
/persons
```

A `GET` call on `/persons/id` returns all the information about a certain person.

A `GET` call on `/persons/id/organizations` returns an array of all the organizations a persons belongs to.

A `GET` call on `/persons/id/organizations/id` returns all the information of a specific organization the person belongs to. It returns the same content as in `/organizations/id`.

There is a possibility to extend the person information with its organizations information, to combine two `GET` into a single `GET`:

```
/persons/id/?expand=organizations
```

My question is about the ETags in the latter request.

When accessing `/persons/id`, an ETag is added to the response headers. Likewise, when accessing `/persons/id/organizations/id`, an ETag is added to the response headers.

The question now: which ETag should I add to the response headers when accessing `/persons/id?expand=organizations`?

In other words, should I update the ETag of a person each time a related organization is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your system. If you have a global ETag then there is no problem. If you have an ETag (or version number) by every entity, and you want to assign ETags to nested representations, then you have a problem... You can define a custom header and send the ETags along with the IRIs (URIs), or you have to add them to the response body. This is not a fully solved problem (at least not by Hydra), we had a discussion about this [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-hydra/2014Sep/0096.html).